# Why am I getting a std::bad_alloc error when trying to push to a vector?

Tags: c++, parsing, vector, bad-alloc

**C++**
Here is the portion of my code that throws the error:

```
IDlist->push_back(lex->getCurrentToken());
```

IDList is a vector that is defined like this:

```
std::vector<Token*>* IDlist;
```

Why can't that line of code push my Token object? Thanks.

EDIT:

When I try this:

```
Token* t = lex->getCurrentToken();
IDlist->push_back(t);
```

I get the same error; it happens when a push into the vector is attempted.

Comment: lex->getCurrentToken() returns pointer? and why IDlist need to be pointer? did you new IDlist?

Comment: maybe the vector needs to be resized but can't allocate enough memory?

Comment: Your code looks good. Try calling `getCurrentToken()` without pushing it to the vector to see if that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I just tried that and I still get the same error - when the push is attempted...

Comment: can you show how do you new IDlist?

Comment: IDlist is a vector. I don't need to use `new` on it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<Token*>* IDlist;
```

IDlist is a pointer which points to a vector and you haven't allocated it by `new`.
You need to allocate IDlist before using it:

```
IDlist = new  std::vector<Token*>();
```

But what's the point of using a pointer to vector? Just declare IDlist as variable:

```
std::vector<Token*> IDlist;
Token* t = lex->getCurrentToken();
IDlist.push_back(t);
```

Comment: I changed it so it's a vector of Token pointers, and now it's working. Thanks